# how to use variable's values like dataframe in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a csv file like below

```
mt,ht,mh,hh,mp,hp
17,24,80,100,200,300
24,17,100,80,300,200
0,16,75,95,175,250
16,0,95,75,250,175
```

when i use read csv, i am able to read it to a dataframe. i changed my program so it will calculate these values and stores it to different variables.

so how can i use those variable to be lika a dataframe(header is not conseidered)

say i have variables giving output like this

```
a= 16
b= 0
c= 95
d= 75
e= 250 
f= 175
```

and let these be in the respective order of mt,ht,mh,hh,mp,hp. so instead of reding from csv,how can i use these values???

my present code :

```
data_to_be_predicted = pd.read_csv('C:\Python34\data\input_data.csv')
prediction = decision_tree.predict(data_to_be_predicted)
print(prediction)
```

what changes have to be made instead of read_csv to use those values that will be calculated before executing this piece of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `DataFrame` constructor with `list`:

```
a= 16
b= 0
c= 95
d= 75
e= 250 
f= 175
L = [a,b,c,d,e,f]

cols = ['mt','ht','mh','hh','mp','hp']
df = pd.DataFrame([L], columns=cols)
#if need same columns as df
#df = pd.DataFrame([L], columns=df.columns)
print (df)

   mt  ht  mh  hh   mp   hp
0  16   0  95  75  250  175
```